# How to align rectangle with textframe?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

**Context**

I would like the `tikz` rectangle to align with the frame in which my text needs to be placed. I assumed it would have something to do with a vertical skip that starts before a `tikzpicture`, but can't seem to find the correct length to adjust (if at all). For example, I have tried setting `parskip` to `0pt`, but that does not seem to prelude a `tikzpicture`.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[centering, a5paper, margin = 1.5cm, bottom = 1cm, top = 1cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt} % does not seem to work
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw[very thick, red](0, 0) rectangle (\linewidth, -\textheight);
\node at (0.5\linewidth, \textheight) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: red rectangle does not match framed text rectangle]

**Question**

How do I need to adjust the code such that these align? Is my assumption of the `textheight` corresponding to the desired height incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space you're seeing above the rectangle is just the first line of the document, where the `tikzpicture` is placed: the origin of the TikZ picture is placed on the baseline of the first line of text, so the rectangle goes down 1 `\textheight` below that. To remove the space, you can move the baseline of the TikZ picture 1 `\baselineskip` above.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[centering, a5paper, margin = 1.5cm, bottom = 1cm, top = 1cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt} % does not seem to work
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, baseline=-\baselineskip]
\draw[very thick, red](0, 0) rectangle (\linewidth, -\textheight);
\node at (0.5\linewidth, -.5\textheight) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wonderful! I knew there had to be something with it starting at the same height as the text normally should, but couldn't come up with searching for `baseline` specifically. Thanks!